# disable syntax highlighting in kile

Tags: highlighting, kile

In the `\verbatim` environment, the syntax highlighting is disabled default, e.g. a `$` ist not recognized as beginning of the math mode. I add my own environtment (`\rawtext`) to the kile Verbatim environments (Settings -> Configure Kile -> LaTeX -> General -> Commands -> Environments)

[image]

However, it is not working:

[image]

What is wrong or what can I do to display my own verbatim environment (kile 2.1.0 under Debian Linux)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Kile does not switch its highlighting rule due to the registered environments. The highlighting is governed by the kate highlighting rules.

Locate the highlighting file `latex.xml`, it should be under `PREFIX/share/apps/katepart/syntax/latex.xml`, where `PREFIX` is the root of your KDE installation, like `/usr` or `/opt`.

Edit this file as follows. First, we have to find your `rawtext` environment, just add it where `verbatim` is detected:

```xml
  <!-- filter the environment name and check the type -->
  <context name="Environment" attribute="Environment" lineEndContext="#stay">
    <RegExpr String="(lstlisting|(B|L)?Verbatim)" attribute="Environment" context="VerbatimEnvParam"/>
    <RegExpr String="(verbatim|boxedverbatim|rawtext)" attribute="Environment" context="VerbatimEnv"/>
    <RegExpr String="(equation|displaymath|eqnarray|subeqnarray|math|multline|gather|align|flalign)" attribute="Environment" context="MathEnv"/>
    <RegExpr String="(alignat|xalignat|xxalignat)" attribute="Environment" context="MathEnvParam"/>
    <DetectChar char="&#xd7;" attribute="Bullet" context="#stay"/>
    <RegExpr String="[a-zA-Z]" attribute="Environment" context="LatexEnv"/>
    <RegExpr String="\s+" attribute="Error" context="#pop"/>
    <RegExpr String="[^a-zA-Z\xd7]" attribute="Error" context="#pop"/>
  </context>
```

Next, the your environment needs to be parsed:

```xml
  <!-- parse verbatim text -->
  <context name="Verbatim" attribute="Verbatim" lineEndContext="#stay">
    <DetectChar char="&#xd7;" attribute="Bullet" context="#stay"/>
    <RegExpr String="\\end(?=\s*\{(verbatim|lstlisting|boxedverbatim|rawtext|(B|L)?Verbatim)\*?\})" attribute="Structure"  context="VerbFindEnd"/>
  </context>
```

Finally, we need to detect the end of that environment:

```xml
  <!-- end of verbatim environment -->
  <context name="VerbFindEnd" attribute="Normal Text" lineEndContext="#pop" fallthrough="true" fallthroughContext="#pop">
    <RegExpr String="\s*\{" attribute="Normal Text" context="#stay"/>
    <RegExpr String="(verbatim|lstlisting|boxedverbatim|rawtext|(B|L)?Verbatim)\*?" attribute="Environment" context="#stay"/>
    <DetectChar char="}" attribute="Normal Text" context="#pop#pop#pop#pop#pop" endRegion="block"/>
  </context>
```

In other words, wherever `verbatim` is handled in the syntax highlighting file, you add `rawtext`.

[image: snapshot]

Comment: this solutions works fine for years, however, now I've updated to Kile 3 beta and it works not anymore. Are there hints to do that?

Comment: with KDE5 the file is used from $HOME/.local/share/org.kde.syntax-highlighting/syntax to find a source, go to https://www.kate-editor.org/syntax/