# Kile syntax highlighting: A single dollar sign in the preamble

Tags: editors, kile, syntax-highlighting

I'm using `Kile` to edit my LaTeX documents. I define my own custom environment to hightlight LaTeX code named `lstLaTeX` with the following code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman,english]{babel}

\usepackage{listings}

\definecolor{lightgrey}{rgb}{0.9,0.9,0.9}
\definecolor{darkgreen}{rgb}{0,0.6,0}

\lstnewenvironment{lstLaTeX}
  {
  \lstset{language=[LaTeX]TeX,
    keepspaces=true,
    texcsstyle=*\bf\color{blue},
    basicstyle=\ttfamily,
    numbers=none,
    breaklines=true,
    keywordstyle=\color{darkgreen},
    commentstyle=\color{red},
    morekeywords={},
    otherkeywords={$, \{, \}, \[, \]},
    frame=none,
    tabsize=2,
    columns=fullflexible,
    backgroundcolor=\color{lightgrey},
    escapechar=°
    }
  }
  {}


\begin{document}
The actual document.
Here some LaTeX code:
\begin{lstLaTeX}
Brackets should be {\bf highlighted}.
The dollar sign: $x=5$
\end{lstLaTeX}

\end{document}
```

The problem is that Kile cannot deal with the single dollar sign in the preamble and marks all following text green (because it thinks there should be a math environment).

[image]

I already read how to teach Kile to ignore dollar signs when used inside custom environments here: [disable syntax highlighting in kile](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/109184/disable-syntax-highlighting-in-kile)
But this post doesn't solve my problem.

So it would be nice if I could tell Kile to ignore this single dollar sign. I already tried to add `%$` at the end of the line with the single dollar sign but Kile ignores this.

Comment: Is simply splitting the input line an option? If so, the 'normal' solution to this type of problem is a strategically-placed comment with the 'matching' item in it.

Comment: I'm not sure if understand your tip corretly (splitting the input line?) but I already tried to solve the problem with a comment and it didn't worked. A custom comment command which Kile doesn't recognize as a comment might be a solution.

Comment: End of the line would be 'wrong' due to the braces, hence asking about splitting the line so you have `{$, % $ <newline> \[, \], ...`. I'm not a Kile user so I can't check if it respects this.

Comment: The problem is Kile marks all following text green not only the line with `$` and it ignores `%$`.

Comment: @JosephWright Is there a way of telling TeX to throw away the next token? Kile is too 'clever' - it ignores anything after a comment sign. I want to use `$` with `l3regex`, but it turns all remaining content in my `.cls` magenta! And obviously repetition isn't an option in this case. (I know I can use `\Z` but that is much less readable for me.

Answer (score 4):

```
otherkeywords={$, $, \{, \}, \[, \]},
```

seems to work. The repetition doesn't seem to bother anything when compiling and it makes Kile happy.

## EDIT

A similar problem, which cannot be worked around in the same way, occurs if using `$` with `l3regex`, for example.

The following function

```
\cs_new_protected_nopar:Nn \prefix_gobble_token:n
{
  \relax
}
```

allows the `$` to be matched, limiting the highlighting damage to the close vicinity of the offending token by adding

```
\cfr_gobble_token:n { $ }
```

close by.

However, I have no idea how safe or otherwise this might be ...

Comment: Just use `\use_none:n $`. (And in regexes if I remember correctly `\Z` is equivalent to `$` except perhaps for subtleties with linefeeds that I never implemented.